# How to send user id to redirect to other path using that id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am trying to redirect the user after the user has registered for an account to edit profile page, but its not working it just sends me back to my home page.

-----------Routes.rb---------------

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



 devise_for :users

 resources :profiles
 resources :events

 root 'staticpages#home'
 get 'staticpages/home'

 get 'calendar' => 'calendar#show'
end
```

-------application_controller.rb------------

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      calendar_path
   end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

-------user.rb-------

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile,  autosave: true, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :events,  autosave: true, :dependent => :destroy

 after_create :create_profile_record
 after_create :create_event_record

private

  def create_profile_record
    Profile.create(:id => id, :user_id => id)
  end

  def create_event_record
    Event.create(:id => id, :user_id => id)
  end
end
```

Comment: where is the redirection?

Comment: def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user)
  end

Comment: that is not a redirection: about redirections please refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: I am using gem devise, there the helper include the redirect, has mention here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-or-sign_up the problem is that it does not redirect to paths that requires id.. which I am not sure how to transfer it to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally got it thanks to @SpunkyLive  , yesterday i tried overwritten it with just one part of the code but it wouldnt work. And I thought its not possible it doesnt make sense. So what I did, I copied the registrations_controller in devise gem this right here 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb
In my own registration_controller that I made, and change directly the

```
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
```

to

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     edit_profile_path(resource)
  end
```

Thanks again for the suggestions, guys. Really appreciate it.